# How to use Facter values in Ruby template with Puppet

Tags: puppet, erb, facter

I am trying to figure out how I can use Facter facts inside a Ruby template erb file configured with Puppet.

Sample Ruby template variable

```
zk.l.conn=
```

Expected config file output from Puppet

```
zk.l.conn=ip-xx-31-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:2181,ip-xxx-31-xx- xxx.ec2.internal:2181,ip-172-xxx-xxx-xx.ec2.internal:2181
```

Facter fact data:

```
"zk-internal": [
  {
    "host": "ip-xx-31-xx-xxx.ec2.internal",
    "port": 2181,
    "priority": 2,
    "weight": 10
  },
  {
    "host": "ip-xxx-31-xx-xxx.ec2.internal",
    "port": 2181,
    "priority": 3,
    "weight": 10
  },
  {
    "host": "ip-172-xxx-xxx-xx.ec2.internal",
    "port": 2181,
    "priority": 1,
    "weight": 10
  }
],
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short:

```
zk.1.conn=<%= @facts['zk-internal'].map { |h| "#{h['host']}:#{h['port']}" }.join(',') %>
```

`@facts['zk-internal']` lets you access the structured fact value, used because `@zk-internal` wouldn't be a valid variable name due to the hyphen.

`.map { |h| "#{h['host']}:#{h['port']}" }` iterates over every element and returns new strings containing "host:port" from each element, so you have an array of hosts/ports returned.

`.join(',')` returns a string from the array with each element comma-separated.

This outputs:

```
zk.1.conn=ip-xx-31-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:2181,ip-xxx-31-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:2181,ip-172-xxx-xxx-xx.ec2.internal:2181
```

(Tested on Puppet 4.7)

Comment: Clever to use `.map` to retain it as an array during iteration so you can use `.join` for the commas.

Comment: Excellent ! but If i need to add port to each ip like example ip-xx-31-xx-xxx.ec2.internal:2181?

Comment: You'd change that in the second part - `.map { |h| "#{h['host']}:#{h['port']}" }` would now return an array of host:port strings.

Comment: I'm glad, I've edited the answer to show the host:port as requested. Please remember to accept the answer (green tick on the left) if it solves the issue.